# all text not changing color on hover

Tags: html, css, angular

The title (af-notification__title), description (af-notification__description) and date (af-notification__date) text color should change to black when the af-notification__content div is hovered.

I have added 'color: black' to the content div

```
 .af-notification__content :hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: #dfeaed;
  }
```

```
<div class="af-notification" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [class.toggled]="toggled">
  <div class="af-notification__content"  [class.delete]="delete">
    <button (click)="deleteWidget(i)" class="btn-close">delete</button>
    <span class="af-notification__title" [class.read]="item['read'] == true">{{ item['title'] }}</span>
    <span class="af-notification__description">{{ item['description'] }}</span>
    <span class="af-notification__date">
      {{ item['date'] }} {{ item['time'] }}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9quulu

If I hover over the af-notification__content div, all text should turn to black. Currently the text only turns black when hovering over each individual span of text.
Would ::ng deep be a good option to use in this case?

Comment: maybe remove space : `.af-notification__content:hover`

Comment: @TemaniAfif that doesnt seem to work

Comment: The space character you have between `.af-notification__content` and `:hover` in CSS ***is a descendant combinator/selector***. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator

Comment: `.af-notification__content:hover *` maybe?

Comment: @connexo When I change it to .af-notification__content:hover it doesn't have the desired behavior - Can you please show me on Stackblitz? 
When the content div is hovered, all text within the div should turn black.

Comment: Your rule mixes two things that are meant for different elements. If you want to set all child elements' text color to black, target those: `.af-notification__content:hover * { color: black; }`. If you want the box to have a blue background-color on hover, target the box and the box only for that: `.af-notification__content:hover { background-color: #dfeaed; }`.

Comment: can you add a relevant minimal html code for this?

Comment: thanks @connexo but if I add .af-notification__content:hover * { color: black; } it changes the color of the border around the button. I only want the text color to be black and background-color to be #dfeaed

Comment: @OmriAttiya please see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9quulu

Comment: Please include all code relevant to the question, in the question itself. Don't make us go off site to find important context like HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
.af-notification:hover .af-notification__title,
.af-notification:hover   .af-notification__date-time {
    color: black;
    background-color: #dfeaed;
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vuvwzw?file=src/app/notification/notification.component.css

Answer (score 0):

Remove space before "hover". There must not be space before hover. Try the code below.

```
.af-notification__content:hover{
color: black;
background-color: #dfeaed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. When I do this modification the title and date dont turn black on hover. please see the notification.component.css file on the updated Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9quulu